T-SQL aggregate counts with a case expression
I need to find counts of transactions for data providers. I need for some of the data providers to roll up into one single result row and the rest to display just there transaction counts. Instead what I keep getting is a single row for every single data provider.
I tried the following statement. I need it to add to count for x if a datasourceid is x,y, or z. And to its own count if not x,y, or z
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN C.Datasourceid IN (x, y, z) THEN x
        ELSE C.Datasourceid
    END AS DatasoureID,
    CASE
        WHEN D.DatasourceName IN ('Mips', 'Yips', 'Zips') THEN 'Mips'
        ELSE D.DatasourceName
    END AS DatasourceName,  
    COUNT(*) AS Transactions
FROM
    ClaimView C, DatasourceView D


    AND C.ReportDate BETWEEN '07/01/2023' AND '6/30/2024'
DatasourceActiveIndicator = 'Y' 

GROUP BY
    C.Datasourceid, DatasourceName
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC

This is what the results would look like without combining some of the datasources:
enter image description here
And this is what I need it to look like:
enter image description here

You don't group by CASE WHENs, so not sure which result you are expecting to get. Also, the old "comma" join, is it really 1980 already

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Also, it's 2024, it is long past time you adopted the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax; it's been around for 32 years. Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs

Please, use your gifts to help people instead of snarking at them. And the ANSI police didn't check with me when they made their decision.

@Zoomer bad questions get no answers. Images can't be copied, compiled, queried or tested, even when they're visible. When you use SO or frankly, ask anyone for help, it's up to you to write a good question. In your shoes I'd be more concerned with the consequences of the bad date strings. Is 07/01 July 1 or January 7? At best you'll get an execution error when you don't expect it. Worst case, you end up selecting the wrong data. That's where all those headlines like 'Pensioner charged $100K for 1 monthor 'Family arrested due to date error' come from.  UseYYYYMMDD` at least

Change your GROUP BY clause to
    GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN C.Datasourceid IN (x, y, z) THEN x
        ELSE C.Datasourceid
    END AS DatasoureID,

so you merge the three groups into one, not just in the selection, but the aggregation too.

You can use a derived table and then group by on the columns of derived table. For example:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataPointSource
CREATE TABLE #DataPointSource (DataSourceId varchar(2) NOT NULL, DataSourceName varchar(100), Cnt int)
INSERT INTO #DataPointSource (DataSourceId, DataSourceName, Cnt)
    VALUES 
          ('a', 'Apple', 1000)
        , ('b', 'Banana', 2000)
        , ('x', 'Fruits', 5000)
        , ('y', 'Orange', 500)
        , ('z', 'Lemon', 500)
        , ('d', 'Peach', 3000)
        , ('e', 'Grapefruit', 2500)

select * from #DataPointSource
select tbl.DataSourceId, tbl.DataSourceName, SUM(tbl.Cnt)
from
    (select 
        case when DataSourceId in ('x','y','z') then 'x' else DataSourceId end as DataSourceId,
        case when DataSourceId in ('x','y','z') then 'Fruits' else DataSourceName end as DataSourceName,
        Cnt
    from #DataPointSource) as tbl
group by tbl.DataSourceId, tbl.DataSourceName

